# Some images appearing small on Iphone Xs

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage

I have an imageset in my imagesscassets with the usual @1x, @2x and @3x.  It appears in the appropriate size on older iphones but the images are smaller on the Xs. Are you supposed to include larger images for the Xs or how are you supposed to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you setting the image?

If it's on storyboard: in attributes, is the content mode "Aspect Fit"? This would have the image render to its biggest resolution size. It might appear smaller on a bigger device. Change the content view to "Scale to fill" and it will fit into the frame you have it with in Xcode.

If you set it programmatically, did you set any attributes/constraints?